# In LibreOffice Calc is there a hotkey to edit the current cell?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I am wanting to edit a column of cells (for example, copy/pasted values have `$0.005/hr` and I want them to just be `0.005`)

I can navigate with arrow keys, I can click to edit the existing value, but would much rather edit the existing value without the use of a mouse.

- press hotkey to edit cell
- press enter to move to next row (same column)
- repeat

As it is I have to move my hand to and from the mouse to click the cell for each edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>F2</kbd>, Same as in Microsoft Excel.

Once done you can press Enter to switch to next row.

Comment: Thank you so much, will mark this correct when it's old enough for me to do so.  I honestly don't use either excel or calc much... main reason I use LibreOffice is I mostly use it to update my resume once in a while... Not much else, so no need to pay $$$ for a lot of features I'll never use.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a difference. If you double click on the formula editor box (usually in the central part of the toolbox ) then you can use shift-enter to insert line breaks in text. But with F2 you cannot, shift-enter has the same effect as enter.

Comment: @am70 F2 works the same way as double clicking, I just check

Comment: BTW F2 also edits the file name in Explorer so it's easy to remember.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use the input line rather than the cell contents editor, use:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

From the [online help section Shortcut Keys](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/scalc/04/01020000.html#hd_id3147366):

> Moves the cursor to the Input line where you can enter a formula for
> the current cell.

If you wish to reassign the shortcut key associated with this command:

- In the application menu choose: "Tools", "Customize"
- In the dialog, choose the "Keyboard" tab
- Choose Category "All commands" and Function "Input Line"